# ElasticSearch/Logstash data gaps

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am using a minimal Logstash setup and the Syslog input to collect execution data from three remote systems.

This works fine but some times there are data gaps. Some log entries available in the original log files do not make it to ElasticSearch.

My question is whether Logstash drops data when the load increases.

If yes, I would like to know:

1. How to confirm that in my case. Is there a way to monitor Logstash
   for such data loses? Will Logstash throw an error or similar?
2. Recommendations for avoiding such data gaps. I already decreased the
   frequency of produced log events. I assume the next step would be to
   take one of the scaling approaches proposed here: [deploying-and-scaling-logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/deploying-and-scaling.html)

Thanks,
Michail

Comment: Check logstash's own logs.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of logstash (1.x) has a very small pipeline queue, and will not accept more messages than that if it becomes congested.  For a file{} input, this isn't a problem, because the file will continue to sit on disk waiting for logstash to resume.  For syslog, which has no buffer, messages would be lost.

The current recommendation is to put a broker in between (redis, rabbitmq), which can grow when logstash is congested.

logstash 2.0 is said to have a real pipeline cache, so an extra broker won't be required.

Comment: 1.5 is 1.x, which is not 2.0.

Comment: Yes Right @Alain Collins